# "Insignificant" or "unsignificant"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives, negative-prefixes

In my job I test different versions of varying degrees on websites. Basically A vs B, and the results of this test determine which version should be developed.

The way a winner is chosen is by looking at the data. We can only take action on statistically **significant** data. When we talk about results some people say "we can't act on this because the data is **insignificant**" whereas I think we should say "we can't act on this because the data is **unsignificant**".

To me, **insignificant** data means it's not interesting/worth noting whereas **unsignificant** data means it hasn't reached statistical significance.

Is there any difference between the two?

(Not sure if this is the right board for this one but as it's about difference of wording I thought I'd start here)

Comment: The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/217965?redirectedFrom=unsignificant#eid) states that 'unsignificant' is an obsolete word. 'Insignificant' bears the meaning which you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you are correct in the usage of the word **Insignificant** in your sentence.

that is, ***"We can't act on this because the data is insignificant"*** [sic]

Merriam-Webster describes [**unsignificant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unsignificant) as:

> lacking meaning or significance : insignificant

Here, unsignificant has a one particular meaning of insignificant<sub>4</sub> i.e. **lacking meaning or import**

On the other hand,

Merriam Webster describes [**insignificant**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insignificant) as:

> : not significant: such as
>
> 1. not worth considering : unimportant
> 2. lacking weight, position, or influence : contemptible
> 3. **small in size, quantity, or number**
> 4. lacking meaning or import

So, you should go for **insignificant**<sub>3</sub> which in your context means:

> not significant because **small in size, quantity, or number**

*Additional information [good to know]: Oxford dictionary does not consider "unsignificant" as word.*

Answer (score 0):

I googled this very issue tonight after came across the word unsignificant on a 20th century poem "Landscape with the Fall of Icarus" in which the word unsignificant was used.

An article I read states that INsignificant is implied to mean "Not of statistical significance" when the connection is research.

NONsignificant is used to speak of unrelated or uninteresting.

UNsignificant seems to be an archaic term but since you need a word for uninteresting, and not statistically significant, I'd say NONsignificant for uninteresting and use insignificant when you speak of variables which failed to reach statistical significance.

This is similar to the neurology terms voluntary, involuntary and involuntary, the later being recently invented (I can think) to explain a movement or vocalization which is semi under ones control but not really voluntary. Like my urge to write this comment to you which I bet will go unread by the person who posted it, some 4 years ago!